# meaning of setting android:text to @+id/xyz

Tags: android, android-layout

What does it mean to set the `android:text` attribute of a view in a layout xml file to something like `@+id/xyz`. An example can be found at https://github.com/freezy/android-xbmcremote/blob/master/res/layout/actor_item.xml

Relevant code copied here:

```
    <TextView 
        android:text="@+id/actor_name" 
        android:id="@+id/actor_name" 
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView 
        android:text="@+id/actor_role" 
        android:id="@+id/actor_role" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Have you read: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

Comment: This is `android:text="@+id/actor_name"` wrong for set text. You can set text as a `android:text="hello"` or `android:text="@string/hello"`. The thing which you have asked is for set id for `TextView`.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't make much sense. According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:text) what you assign to `android:text` must be a string value:

> Must be a string value, using `\\;` to escape characters such as `\\n` or `\\uxxxx` for a unicode character.
>
> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.

Values of `@id` are integers.

Comment: Weird thing though is that the project can compile just fine. Maybe compiler ignores the setting?

Comment: @dacongy Hmm, not sure about the compiler... But what does it do when you run it?

Answer (score 1):

"@+id/id" means you are giving a unique name or id for `textview` which will help to identify that `textview` and `android:text` is like body of the `textview` u can give anything which u want to display.

Answer (score 0):

"android:text" requires to set String to it.  It's the text that will appear in the TextView.

You can either use a plain string or use @string to extract the string from res/values/strings.xml

```
<TextView 
    android:text="@string/actor_name" 
    android:id="@+id/actor_name" 
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

"@+id/id" is a kind of action that tells the android framework to create an id.  The plus symbol, +, indicates that this is a new resource ID and will be created if doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

please visit http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id

The plus (+) sign just indicates it that the ID should be created if it is not under existence at the moment.

It is  a general practice to use @+id/something when defining a new View in a layout, and then later  use @id/something to reference the View from another part of the layout (say, in any RelativeLayout ) or R.id.something to reference it from   our java code.